# Two files, same permissions, Apache says one is forbidden

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions, file-permissions

I have two files in a directory that is accessible to the Interent.  It's part of a WordPress installation.  Here are the directory contents:

```
# ls -lah
total 11M
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 2.9M Jul  6 01:49 June_16.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 2.6M Jul  5 14:17 June_23.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 2.4M Jul  5 14:17 June_30.pdf
... few other files...
```

They all have the same permissions.  Except I can view / download two of the files, but cannot view / download the one of them.  For the one I cannot view / download, Apache gives a 403 forbidden failure.  It happens for this pdf file no matter what directory I put it in.

On my local machine (MacOs), I can view the file and it's a valid pdf.
I also cannot upload this PDF file via the WordPress Media Upload page.

What could be going on here?

Just FYI here are links to the files:

https://www.qctonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/June_16.pdf

https://www.qctonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/June_23.pdf

https://www.qctonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/June_30.pdf

Answer (score 1):

1. Look through your apache access and error logs in /var/logs/, there should be more details there.
2. Try renaming the file to see if it is name-related. There could be something in your .htaccess that's causing this.

Comment: The `ssl_error_log` just complaining about the permissions, not a `client denied by server configuration`: [Tue Jul 06 03:42:46.151641 2021] [core:error] [pid 29936] (13)Permission denied: [client 1.2.3.4:50762] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /var/www/html/web-root-dir/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/June_16.pdf

Comment: Change file name, issue persists with new filename.

Comment: My mind is boggled.  I was considering malware, since the same file could not be uploaded into the media store page of WordPress.

Comment: Have you tried saving/exporting the PDF to a new pdf file?

Comment: Yes, I tried that using Mac Preview app.

Comment: Is this a Redhat/CentOS box by any chance? SELinux?

Comment: Yes, it is.  SELinux is enforcing and read permissions has been given to the directory where all the files are stored together.  I don't know about any more advanced SELinux settings that would block a particular file.